# How time consuming it is to every time INSERT in several tables?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

Would like to get some input from you regarding this.

Let's say I have a table T with 10 columns. 
Let's also say that for each 10 columns there is a separate table with relative data.

So, every time when I want to insert data into table T I also need to insert data to other 10 tables, so it's 11 tables in total.

How time consuming it is? 
At what number of columns/tables it gets time consuming?

Comment: You have to test your processes on your data in your databases in your hardware.  We cannot decide what is and is not acceptable.  We can point out that you might have a suspect data structure if you have to update so many tables at one time.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, thanks for your hint. My question probably sounded too concrete but I just wanted to know in general do people do this? Is it better to have big but 1 table?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same delima. My solution is to use an Excel Template and Concatenate all the cells once I have filled out all the rows I need inserted.

Excel Column A contains the following SQL Statement

```
INSERT INTO [TableName] (ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, ColumnD, ColumnE, ColumnF, ColumnG, ColumnH, ColumnI, ColumnJ) VALUES ('
```

Excel Column B has the values for ColumnA

Excel Column C contains the following

```
'', '
```

*Please note that that is a double apostrophe, its needed because the first apostrophe is telling the Excel cell it is to be treated as text, so it disappears in the cell and the concatenation.*

Rinse and repeat, Your final Excel Column to complete the insert statement will be the following

```
'')
```

Last step is your simple concatenation.

This is the fastest solution I have found so far with the type of databases I take care of which consist of mostly Product information for web stores and marketplaces.

I have given the Market Teams here an Excel Template that has the same column headers as my Insert Template so when they want to add new products or update existing data its a simple copy/paste for me.

To Answer your question. It does not take long.

Hope this helps you.